# meteor 0.9 not finding npm dependencies specified by a package

Tags: meteor, npm

I have an application that began in meteor 0.6.0 and has been progressively updated to the current 0.9.3.1 version.

The app uses a local package called "app" which is in ./pacakges/app and it has a package.js file that looks like this:

**./packages/app/package.js**

```
Package.describe({

    summary: "App SDK",

    version: "1.0.0"

});


Package.onUse(function (api) {

    api.versionsFrom( '0.9.3.1' );




    api.addFiles([

        "app.js"

    ], "server");


    api.export([
        'amqp',
        'eyes',
        'fiber',
        'eyes',
        'pretty',
        'sax',
        'xml_writer'
    ], "server" );

});

Npm.depends({
    "eyes": "0.1.8",
    "amqp": "0.1.6",
    "fibers": "1.0.0",
    "pretty-data": "0.40.0",
    "sax": "0.5.4",
    "xml-writer": "1.2.4"
});
```

This used to work, but I recently checked out a working copy on a new machine and I get the following error when I start meteor:

```
app: updating npm dependencies -- eyes, amqp, fibers, pretty-data, sax, xml-writer...
W20141003-09:50:13.172(-7)? (STDERR)
W20141003-09:50:13.239(-7)? (STDERR) /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.vvwxrr++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141003-09:50:13.239(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141003-09:50:13.239(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141003-09:50:13.240(-7)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'eyes'
W20141003-09:50:13.240(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20141003-09:50:13.240(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20141003-09:50:13.240(-7)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20141003-09:50:13.241(-7)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20141003-09:50:13.241(-7)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/mnt/disk2/applications/myapp/source/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:95:18)
W20141003-09:50:13.241(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.data_sync.js:10:24
W20141003-09:50:13.241(-7)? (STDERR)     at /mnt/disk2/applications/myapp/source/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:5
```

Since there's a mention of cordova there, I assume this has to do with the recent introduction of that platform to meteor. I am not targeting mobile platforms in my app, so I could remove it if that would help.

The question is, am I missing something to get these npm dependencies honoured?

Comment: Maybe try `rm -rf .npm` at the root of your package to clear npm related cache.

Comment: make sure the deps are specified in a package.json, then run `npm install`

Comment: @Joseph isn't Npm.depends supposed to install them automatically?

Comment: @saimeunt no dice either.

Comment: @thatjuan It is - but have a go.

Comment: @Joseph that works, but if meteor says it's "updating npm dependencies" why do I have to npm install again?

Comment: I have no idea. Meteor is in beta - so your problem is solved by this hacky workaround?

Comment: @Joseph i found that the npm dependencies are getting installed correctly by Meteor itself in its internal file structure .meteor/programs/server/... etc but some component of it is looking for these packages in the project's root path. The hacky install fixes the error, but the goal of this question is to find out why. It's got to be some legacy config in my project because blank projects work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case was that there were calls to Npm.require() outside of the package. I had assumed that npm dependencies set by a package would be made available to the application itself, but that is not true.

In my case I just exported some of the NPM packages I needed through api.export() and removed any Npm.require() calls from the app (except Npm.require('fibers') which is allowed).

There's also [this package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) which allows Npm.require() without packages.